# Empty cookies using Python and Selenium whit get_cookies() function

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm doing a "stupid" bot with Python and Selenium to automate some actions on web.telegram.org.
I want stay logged in after the first log on, but when I try to save cookie with function `driver.get_cookies()` they are empty (I tryed to print them and the output was "[]"). When I did the same thing with other website like youtube.com for example, it works! I tryed also using different webDrivers but I got the same results.
The code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import pickle

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://web.telegram.org')

time.sleep(4)

phone_number = driver.find_element_by_name("phone_number")
phone_number.send_keys("3478995060")
login_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name("login_head_submit_btn")
login_button.click()
time.sleep(2)
ok_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@my-i18n='modal_ok']")
ok_button.click()

time.sleep(30)

all_cookies = driver.get_cookies()
print(all_cookies)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Can you put the lines `all_cookies = driver.get_cookies()` and `print(all_cookies)` just after `time.sleep(4)` and see what happens?

Comment: @Alichino I tried, same problem: it's empty!
I think it's Telegram Web problem...

Comment: Hmm could it be they don't use cookies? :D

Comment: @Alichino And have you any ideas to stay logged in in my bot? You know other methods?

Comment: So you log in, run a test, quit the driver and then run another test? If you don't quit the driver and run your tests one after another, the session won't be closed. Run all of your tests and only at the very end execute driver.quit(). Sorry I can't help more, but I don't have an account  with Telegram, so can't examine what happens when you log in :(

Comment: @Alichino No problem. The real problem is the one time password: every time i have to log in Telegram send me an OTP to put in the login session. If it did not exist i could do the login every time, and this can't be automated. Thank's for your time dude!

Comment: @Alessandro Lunardi were you able to solve this problem, as I am facing the same problem with telegram but can't bypass the OTP?